# How can I get shadows to render in RealityKit when loading models directly from usdz files rather than a Reality Composer file?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

When adding a model directly to a scene anchor from a usdz file, there are no grounding shadows appearing under the model. These appear if you import the model into RealityComposer and add the RealityComposer scene. But can you enable grounding shadows without using RC?

I have tried adding a DirectionalLight to the scene, but this is not casting any shadows. I have also tried changing the RenderingOptions on the ARView.

```swift
//no shadows
  penguin = try? Entity.loadModel(named: "penguin", in: nil)
  penguinAnchor.addChild(penguin!)

//shadows
  penguinScene = try! PenguinRC.loadPenguinScene()
  arView.scene.addAnchor(penguinScene)
```

Comment: I've got the same problems – no solutions found yet. However, a pre-baked shadow texture projected onto a plane could be a solution possibly. Hoping for Apple to fix it though.

Answer (score 3):

I made some progress with this issue.

Casting shadows from loaded USDZs seems to rely on the Entity (or better) ModelEntity to be added to an AnchorEntity with via a plane initializer rather than a simple AnchorEntity() like so:

```
 let penguinAnchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal, classification: .any, minimumBounds: [0.1, 0.1])
```

Not 100% sure if this is really the part which resolved my issue though.

Comment: This definitely fixed it for me, before that I was using a plain `Entity` subclass as the anchor for my model and I didn't see any shadows. Now, using an `AnchorEntity` it immediately starts working.