# Adding ground shadows to a USDZ model in RealityKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

For some time now, I have been trying to add a realistic ground shadow to an object in RealityKit.  For my use case, I will not be using Reality Composer, nor (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926965/how-can-i-get-shadows-to-render-in-realitykit-when-loading-models-directly-from) question) will I be using an anchor entity from a horizontal plane (my user will tap to place an object and that tap could align with either a horizontal plane *or* an ARMeshAnchor, as we support LiDAR in our app).

When I test my USDZ model via QuickLook on iOS, I see that iOS adds a shadow beneath my model, and while not wholly realistic, it appears a bit more "placed" on a surface, as compared to no shadow.

In trying to add my model, I am taking the following steps;

```
self.model = Entity.load(named: "model.usdz")
```

When a user taps on the screen, I perform a raycast and add the model to the built anchor;

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
   for anchor in anchors {
      if anchor.name == "tapped" {
         let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
         anchorEntity.addChild(self.model!)
         arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
      }
   }
}
```

When the model is added to the tapped point, there are no ground shadows.  As a test, I had gone down the path of trying to add a Directional Light, believing that its placement may cast a light on the object and, therefore, create shadows.  I create the light like so;

```
class Lighting: Entity, HasDirectionalLight {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.light = DirectionalLightComponent(color: .white, intensity: 5000, isRealWorldProxy: true)
    }
}
```

I've added a global `var lightEntity = AnchorEntity()`.  Then, in my `viewDidLoad` method, I am attempting to set up the light like so;

```
let spotLight = Lighting().light
let shadow = Lighting().shadow
lightAnchor.components.set(shadow!)
lightAnchor.components.set(spotLight)
arView.scene.anchors.append(lightAnchor)
self.model = Entity.load(named: "model.usdz")
```

While I can see that there *is* a light shining on the object, it does not seem to cause any shadows to be cast.

Comment: Have you managed to sort out this problem? In my scenario I am forced to use ARAnchors and bind to them, but when I create an AnchorEntity, either like this:
``let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity (plane: .any); anchorEntity.anchoring = AnchoringComponent (anchor)`` or like this: ``let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity (anchor: anchor)`` there is no shadow from the placed object. Shadow appears only if I create ``let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity (plane: .any)``and don't elaborate on AnchoringComponent for it.

Answer (score 1):

if your app supports LiDAR , you can use

```
arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.receivesLighting)
```